# ElementClickInterceptedException on cucumber parallel AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, cucumber-jvm

I have parallel  test setup in `cucumber 6.9.1` using `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` and then directing the test to a grid using RemoteWebDriver

```
 @Override
  @DataProvider(parallel = true)
  public Object[][] scenarios() {
    return super.scenarios();
  }
}
```

and creating RemoteWebDriver like below

```
 String hubURL = "http://192.168.1.7:65299/wd/hub";
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/../../geckodriver");
                 
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();                   
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);              
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.merge(capabilities);
                    return driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options);
```

It opens two instances of firefox , and they overlap each other and I keep getting

`org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <button class="btn btn-link pull-right"` on one or the other  instance of firefox .

I have tried several solutions mentioned in many questions but none of them seems to help in my scenario

I tried below solutions

1. `global.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(PageObjects.AddUser));`
2. `global.jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", PageObjects.AddUser);`
3. `PageObjects.AddUser.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
4. ```
     Actions builder = new Actions(global.driver); 
                       Action clickElement = (Action) builder.click(PageObjects.AddUser);
                       clickElement.perform();
   ```
5. global.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By) PageObjects.allDom));

I am running test on FF 77.0 and Mac OS (catalina)

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT**.  To include `ThreadLocal` change

```
public class FirefoxManager extends DriverManager{
    

    private final ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
         @Override
         protected RemoteWebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException , IOException {
                                 
                ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                            
                  System.out.println("hubport from sys prop var.."+System.getProperty("hub.port"));
                  String hubURL = "http://192.168.1.7:65299/wd/hub";
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/amit/Desktop/amit/projects/misc/geckodriver");
                 
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                
                   
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);                  
                    
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.merge(capabilities);
                 
                   driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options));
                   return driver.get();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved cucumber parallelism using [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) . It worked out of the box and run parallel test at scenario level

Simply inlclude similar runner class in cucumber. My tests are further using `RemoteWebdriver` to open multiple instances on selenium grid. Make sure grid is up and running and node is registered to the grid.

```
import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        rerunAttempts = 1,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
        reportTargetDir = "build",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                glue = "com.test.stepdefs",                   
                publish = true,
                plugin = {
                        "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
        ))
class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
}
```

RemoteWebdriver config is

```
protected RemoteWebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException , IOException {
                   
                 Properties properties = new Properties();                
                ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();                
                  String hubURL = "http://192.168.1.7:65299/wd/hub";
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/amit/Desktop/amit/projects/misc/geckodriver");
                 
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);    
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.merge(capabilities);                 
                   driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options));
                   return driver.get();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ThreadLocal since WebDriver is not ThreadSafe.

copied code, but idea is same

```
protected ThreadLocal<WebDriver> wbdriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
String url = "https://google.com";
wbdriver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
wbdriver.get().manage().window().maximize(); 
wbdriver.get().get(url);
```

Comment: I tried this but I got same error `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <button class="btn btn-link pull-right" type="add"> is not clickable at point (1380,80)` . I also edited above to include change that I did